# Boot Loader for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, grub, bootloader, opensuse

I asked

I have Windows 7 and opensuse 13.1 and Windows boot loader is replaced by grub 2.

Now I want to format opensuse

how can i restore my Windows boot loader over grub 2. How can I format opensuse 13.1 from Windows 7 Please guide me thanks and regards

Your reply was :

You will need a Windows 7 DVD to run Startup repair - this will repair your bootloader and Windows 7 will boot as normal.

new question
now i am in another problem that as i ran startup repair, it restarted and nothing is booting and a message appears that "Multiple active partitions"

so now what should i

Answer (score 2):

Fix for **Multiple active partitions:**

Get a Linux live CD (I would recommend Ubuntu or any GParted containing live CD). Boot from it, open GParted and look at all the partitions. Remove the `active` flag from all **except** the Windows one or the System Reserved one). Also check if there are more than one `boot` flags. Also remove these leaving only one. Reboot.

Fix **Windows 7 bootloader**:

Get a Windows installation or recovery DVD and boot from it. When prompted with the Installation screen choose **Repair my computer**. Open a command prompt and type:

```
bootsect /fixmbr
bootsect /fixboot
```

Restart. It will boot into Windows from now on.

**Delete Linux** partitions:

In Windows, right-click **My computer**, **Manage** then **Disk Management**. Delete Linux partitions and then make new one(s).